# ERC-1155 events for approval

Tags: events, erc-1155

ERC-1155:

```
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _id, uint256 _currentValue, uint256 _value) external;

    /**
        @dev Allow other accounts/contracts to spend tokens on behalf of msg.sender
        Also, to minimize the risk of the approve/transferFrom attack vector
        (see https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YLPtQxZu1UAvO9cZ1O2RPXBbT0mooh4DYKjA_jp-RLM/), this function will throw if the current approved allowance does not equal the expected _currentValue, unless _value is 0
        @param _spender        Address to approve
        @param _ids            IDs of the CryptoItems
        @param _currentValues  Expected current values of allowances per item type
        @param _values         Allowance amounts per item type
    */
    function batchApprove(address _spender, uint256[] calldata _ids, uint256[] calldata _currentValues, uint256[] calldata _values) external;
```

Which events (and with which arguments) should these two functions emit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two functions are not part of the EIP-1155 (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155).
In fact, the EIP only defines :

```
    /**
    @notice Enable or disable approval for a third party ("operator") to manage all of the caller's tokens.
    @dev MUST emit the ApprovalForAll event on success.
    @param _operator  Address to add to the set of authorized operators
    @param _approved  True if the operator is approved, false to revoke approval
*/
function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external;
```

However, the method `approve` you mentioned has been implemented [here](https://github.com/enjin/erc-1155/blob/master/contracts/ERC1155AllowanceWrapper.sol) as an extension to the ERC1155 contract to enable allowance for specific Ids.

Answer (score 0):

The [ERC-1155 specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155#approval) recommends EIP-1761 Scoped Approval Interface as a method to allow specific token approvals: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1761